# JQuery Autocomplete source is a function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery UI autocomplete, for different fields. To get the data i'm using a function as the source. It work great!
I was wondering if there were a way of not using the anonym function in the source, but to declare a generic one which will have a parameter to redirect to the right URL. 
I'm quite new in JS and JQuery and so I have no idea of what the parameters request and response are comming from in the anonym function.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    $ac.autocomplete({
        //Call the function here, but what are the parameter request and response???
        source: autocomplete(),
        minLength: 1
    });
```

Here is the function I'd like to call

```
function autoComplete(request, response, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Comp/'+url,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                return { label: item, value: item, id: item };
            }));
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
source: autoComplete
```

instead of

```
source: autocomplete()
```

One more remark. The default implementation of jQuery UI Autocomplete use only `value` and `label` and not use `id`.

Comment: ID is a default field, see the example source code here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: @FelixEve: Sorry, but I disagree with you. [The documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) describes only two standard representation of the server response: array of strings and array of items with `value` and `label` properties. If the items have some other custom properties the properties will be just saved, but not used in any way by jQuery UI Autocomplete. One have to overwrite [_renderItem](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) method for example to use the properties like `id` during rendering or selection.

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting ur question will pose as solution to  the problem .:)

```
 $ac.autocomplete({
     minLength: 1 ,
     source: function(request, response, url){
                var searchParam  = request.term;

    $.ajax({
              url: '/Comp/'+url,
             data : searchParam,
             dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return { 
                        label: item.Firstname,
                        value: item.FirstName
                        };
                    });
                    }
            });//ajax ends 
            }
 }); //autocomplete ends
```

The *request* and *response* objects are expected by jQuery UI . The **request.term** will give u the  text that the user types and the **response** method will return the *label* and *value* items to the widget factory for displaying the suggestion dropdown

**P.S :** assuming ur JSON string contains a *FirstName* key !

Answer (score 1):

I will give an example of a situation that happened to me, might serve as an example:

Situation: After the user selects a keyword with Jquery Autocomplete not allow it to be listed. Taking into account that the query is executed the same, ie the unamended cat. server-side.

The code looked like this:

```
$( "#keyword-search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 3 ,
    source: function( request , response ) {
        var param = { keyword_type: type , keyword_search: request.term } ;
        $.ajax({
            url: URI + 'search-to-json',
            data : param,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function( item ) {
                    /* At this point I call a function, I use to decide whether to add on the list to be selected by the user. */
                    if ( ! is_record_selected( item ) ) {
                        return item;
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    } ,
    select: function( event , ui ) {
        /* Before you add, looking if there is any cell */
        /* If it exists, compare the id of each cell not to add an existing */
        if ( validate_new_keyword( ui ) ) {
            add_cell( ui ) ;
        }
    } ,
});

/* Any validation... */
function validate_new_keyword( ui ) {
    var keyword_id = $.trim(ui.item.id) ;
    Any condition...
    if (keyword_id > 0) {
        return true ;           
    }

    return false ;
}

/* This function checks if a keyword has not been selected by the user, it checks for the keyword_array. */
function is_record_selected( item ) {
    var index = jQuery.inArray( item.id , keyword_array ) ;
    return index == -1 ? false : true;
}
```

Obs: Thus it is possible to use a function inside "source" and "select". =p